# Focus visability gets lost when element is shown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page with many drop down menus, which are visible on hover event, using css. However, I also want to make them visible when I press tab and they are on focus using jquery. I tried this:

and the following happens:

```
$("body").keydown( function(e) { 
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
        if (keyCode === 9) {

            $("*").bind("focus",function(){
            var $self = $(this);

                if($self.siblings("*:hidden").length > 0){
                    hidden_menu = $self.next("*:hidden");
                    if($(hidden_menu).is("ul")){
                        $(hidden_menu).show();
                        $(hidden_menu).children().addClass("shownhidden");                        
                    }
                }  
                $("*").unbind("focus");            
            })
        }
        $("*").focusout(function(){           
            if(!$(this).next().is(".shownhidden") && $(this).is(".shownhidden")){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(hidden_menu).hide();
                },1000)
            }
        });
});
```

1. when i the mouse over each button the corresponding drop down menu is visible
2. after that, i press tab and when each button becomes focused, the corresponding menus is visible
3. but after that, when i try to mouse over buttons, the corresponding menus don't show up.

the html code is composed of many elements like this below:

```
           <li id="navMenuButton" class="dropdown">
              <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
              <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
```

The css code for this part is:

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #9AEDF3;
    padding: 14px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: can you please post the css and the html you are using?

Comment: I included the css and html code above

Answer (score 0):

Your JQuery function appears to be hiding something that you don't expect. As a result, when you attempt to dsisplay the menu block nothing shows.

A quick and simple test would be to change this in your CSS file from this

```
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

to this

```
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content,  .dropdown:hover li, .dropdown:hover a {
    display: block;
}
```

If this works, then read on...

From the code, you appear to be trying to control visibility solely via the **.dropdown-content** class (which is also the **ul** tag).

I believe that your JQuery class is not only hiding the **ul** element but also some of the elements in that tag (most likely the **li** elements). Since your CSS does not account for that, they never show again.

Here you assign the shownhidden class to the children of the **ul** element. (Q: did you mean to assign to the hidden_menu class itself ?)

```
$(hidden_menu).show();
$(hidden_menu).children().addClass("shownhidden");
```

Since **li** elements are also hidden (via the parent), this code matches for them also (they have **a** elements which would pass the sibling test). Thus an **li** element could be assigned to hidden_menu.

```
$("*").bind("focus",function(){
var $self = $(this);
if($self.siblings("*:hidden").length > 0) {
   hidden_menu = $self.next("*:hidden");
   ...
}
```

And this code would hide the undesired element.

```
$("*").focusout(function(){
    if(!$(this).next().is(".shownhidden") && $(this).is(".shownhidden")){
        setTimeout(function(){
        $(hidden_menu).hide();
```

If this is the issue (quick test given at the beginning of this post), then you can either:
a) check for class type before assigning hidden_menu 
b) check for class type before using hidden_menu (in particular before hiding)
c) add CSS block like the one given above to show everything under the ul element when hovered

Comment: Thank you so much for your erudite answer. However, I didn't solve the problem. The main reason is that I hide an element (dropdown menu) when tab is pressed, using jquery, and then I can't make this element visible when i hover on the button.

Comment: Hi, did you try to look at the status of the hidden elements in the Chrome (or other browser) development tools ?  If you look at the element and the corresponding CSS for the entire hierarchy it should give you a hint to whats going on.